# simple differentation - help

Tags: implicit-differentiation, regular-expressions

how do you differentiate the expression vt with respect to x i.e. (d/dx)(vt) ?

I know this is pretty simple but my mind has gone completely blank

any help would be greatly appreciated! thank you :)

Comment: What is vt? Is it a function of x? Or a constant times t? Or something else?

Comment: vt is the distance traveled by a certain object (speed(v) x time(t))

Comment: Ok, now it depends. The velocity $v$ is constant, and $t$ is a variable. So $x$ is a function of $t$. Then you have that $x(t) = x_0 + vt$. What do you get if you differentiate both sides?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember the product rule from calculus: If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are two differentiable functions of $x$, then $h(x) = f(x)g(x)$ is differentiable and its derivative is given by
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}h(x) = \frac{d}{dx} (f(x)g(x)) = f(x)\frac{dg(x)}{dx}+\frac{df(x)}{dx}g(x).
\end{align}
I do not know how your problem is formulated, e.g. does $v$ and $t$ depend on $x$? Regardless, we have
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}(vt) = t\frac{dv}{dx}+\frac{dt}{dx}v.
\end{align}
Then, for example if $t$ does not depend on $x$, then the first term will be zero, or if $v$ does not depend on $x$, then the second term will be zero.